# Возможно ли сделать с помощью indexOf функцию которая проверяет два массива, и если элементы совпадают, то их нужно удалить

Tags: javascript, функции, indexof

Возможно ли данную функцию сделать с помощью `indexOf()`?

Если да, то подскажите пожалуйста, как бы я мог это осуществить.

```
var array = ["a","b","c","d"];

function func_insert_array(){
    var get_array = document.getElementById("insert_array").value;
            console.log(get_array);
    var separation = get_array.split(",");
            console.log(separation);
    for (var i = 0; i < separation.length; i++) {

        var deleteIndex;

        var array_2 = array.filter(function(value, index) {

            if (value == separation[i]) {
                deleteIndex = index;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (array_2.length > 0) {
            var windows = confirm("такое значение уже есть " + array[deleteIndex]);
            if (windows == true) {
                array.splice(deleteIndex,1);
            }
        }
        console.log(array);

        if (array_2.length == 0 ) {
            array.push(separation[i]);
        }
            console.log(array_2);


    }
    document.getElementById("arr").innerHTML = array;
}
```

Comment: А вам нужно именно `.indexOf()`, есть более удобные методы, как `includes()`

Comment: Желательно indexOf, но я бы с удовольствием и посмотрел бы на вариант с includes.

Comment: переменная `array` на  10 страке (???) откуда

Comment: Оу, она выше, не вставил её. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: добавь пример второго массива. и ожидаемый результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал функцию таким образом, вопрос решен.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
function func_insert_array() {
        var get_array = document.getElementById("insert_array").value;
        var separation = get_array.split(",");
        console.log(separation);


        for (var i = 0; i < separation.length; i++) {
            var deleteIndex = array.indexOf(separation[i]);

            if (deleteIndex >= 0) {
                var windows = confirm("Такой элемент уже существует, удалить его? " + array[deleteIndex]);
                if (windows == true) {
                    array.splice(deleteIndex,1);
                }
            }
            if (deleteIndex == -1) {
                array.push(separation[i]);
            }
            console.log(separation[i]);
            console.log(deleteIndex);
        }




        console.log(array);
        document.getElementById("arr").innerHTML = array;
    }
```